# Controlling Gameobjects through a live text feed || Unity Beginner

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am getting started in Unity because I want to develop an application in which the game objects (such as players, balls etc.) can be controlled depending on a live text feed. I am not very sure about the programming features or any specific libraries/packages which would allow me to do so. Eg. If a text feed mentions, "RUN 5 metres to the North", I want my game object to move 5 metres(including certain animations) in a specific direction. Is it possible to do so in Unity? This is a very general question but as a beginner, I want to get started in the right direction. Google search throws up a Text based game Unity Live tutorial but that is quite different from this.

Comment: Sure this is possible ... but your question is far to broad. You will need an [InputField](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html) probably a [Button](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button) to confirm and than have to come up with a way to parse the input. Last hint: `if (string.Contains("someValue"))` is a good startpoint for checking if a string contains a certain value, `string.IndexOf("abc")` can tell you at which position

Comment: Also look here: https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/reacting-string-input from the [Live Session: Text Adventure Game Part 1](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/introduction-and-goals?playlist=17117)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the quick response! Can I have an InputField with dynamic values derived from a live text feed?

Comment: what is a `live text feed`?

Comment: I want to pick out key phrases/words from a collection of paragraphs.Those words would signify actions eg. RUN, THROW, etc. @derHugo

Comment: sure you can ... you can do a lot of stuff ... you might want to use e.g. [Dropdown](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html) for display a list with options

Comment: I agree with derHugo: this question is really broad. One exercise that helps me is writing out what I want to do and breaking the sentence down to its most basic parts. i.e. "I want this object to move by text". Remove the prepositional phrase "by text" and figure out how to move the object first. After that, add in the functionality to consume text. Then, connect the two parts.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs @Eliasar ! I will sure update what I am upto here in this post sometime in the future :) Meanwhile, the suggestion of breaking down is what I would love to stick to !